# Use Regex in Dynamical Approach

Tags: c#, regex

Today I can do the hard code but later I would like to change it that the string word pattern can be applied in side of the @"\bfood\b". I want to make it into dynamical without using hardcoding

IN the futore I would like to have the word "chicken" instead of "food".

I tried to replace the code `"@"\bfood\b"` into `@"\b" + pattern +"\b"` but it doesn't work.

```
    string inputText = "food ddd dd";

    string dddd = "\bfood\b";

    string pattern = "food";
    Regex rx = new Regex(@"\bfood\b", RegexOptions.None);
    MatchCollection mc = rx.Matches(inputText);

    if (rx.Match(pattern).Success)
    {
        int dd = 3;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
@"\b" + Regex.Escape(pattern) + @"\b"
```

Or a more generic:

```
@"(?<!\w)" + Regex.Escape(pattern) + @"(?!\w)"
```

Or with the `string.format`:

```
Regex rx = new Regex(string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", Regex.Escape(pattern)), RegexOptions.None);
```

Or with the string interpolation:

```
Regex rx = new Regex($@"(?<!\w){Regex.Escape(pattern)}(?!\w)", RegexOptions.None);
```

Now, why do I suggest `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)` lookarounds? Because these are word boundaries that are not context dependent. What if you  decide to pass a `|border|` pattern? The `\b\|border\|\b` will most probably fail to match most of the cases you intended to match because `\b` will require a word character to appear before the first `|` and after the last `|`. The lookarounds will match the `|border|` string only if not enclosed with word characters.

Comment: I wouldn't use `string.Format` here, without `Regex.Escape`. Maybe `string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", Regex.Escape(pattern))`, unless the app is allowing the user to actually type in the Regex to search for, which is rarely the case.

Comment: @AndersTornbladL I agree. I added my reasoning together with sample regex declarations.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your `@"\b" + pattern +"\b"` didn't work is that the verbatim string literal `@` wasn't applied to **both** pieces of your regex building.

Fix this with either

```
@"\b" + pattern + @"\b"
```

Or even better use `String.Format()`

```
String.Format(@"\b{0}\b", pattern);
```

Or use C#6 string interpolation

```
$@"\b{pattern}\b";
```